# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings getting Error in Project installer

Tags: c#, configuration, configurationmanager

```
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class ProjectInstaller : Installer
    {
        private ServiceInstaller m_serviceInstaller;
        private ServiceProcessInstaller m_processInstaller;


        public ProjectInstaller()
        {            
            string Names= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Names"].ToString();
            System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            m_serviceInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
            m_processInstaller = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
            // 
            // serviceProcessInstaller1
            // 
            m_processInstaller.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
            m_processInstaller.Password = null;
            m_processInstaller.Username = null;
            // 
            // serviceInstaller1
            //       
            m_serviceInstaller.ServiceName = "Testing" + Names;
            m_serviceInstaller.DisplayName = "Testing" + Names;
            m_serviceInstaller.Description = "Testing" + Names;
            // 
            // ProjectInstaller
            // 
            this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[] {
            m_processInstaller,
            m_serviceInstaller});
        }
    }
```

My Project installer code as above , It will not get any compile error , but when I try to install it will Rollback , because it will throw exception System.Null referenceException. I also have double confirm that my AppConfig without any problem.

```
  <appSettings>       
    <add key="Names" value="BOC" />
  </appSettings>
```

May I know where is going wrong.

Comment: Please check that config file is published/copied in the running path of your app

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Looks like by default during the service install phase we're reading <frameworkpath>\InstallUtil.exe.Config (e.g. C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe.Config).

A workaround is to load the right config manually:

```
using System.Reflection;
...

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

KeyValueConfigurationElement element = config.AppSettings.Settings["Names"];

string names = null;
if (element != null)
    names = element.Value;
```